# com.segment.analytics.android:analytics noncompliant version in my app on the Google Play Console

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-developers-console, segment-analytics

My app is written on android native code and I got this warning on the play store console

Your app "appName" version code "xxxx" includes SDK **com.segment.analytics.android:analytics** or an SDK that one of your libraries depends on, which collects personal or sensitive data that includes but may not be limited to Advertising ID, Android ID identifiers. Persistent device identifiers may not be linked to other personal and sensitive user data or resettable device identifiers as described in the User Data policy.

ACTION REQUIRED: Upload a new compliant version AND deactivate the noncompliant version.

But I don't have that library on my project, the only libraries related to firebase that I have are these:

```
"com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.4.0",
"com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2",
"com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.0.2",
"com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.0",
"com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.1",
"com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1",
```

But I don't know how to solve this, should I update all of them and upload my app again and check if I received this warning again or not to see if it was solved? I need to solve this because I won't be able to upload more app versions in the following months.

Thank you for being so helpful, it's really appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have the same problem and I am still looking for a solution

Comment: Yes I did, I posted my solution here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people have asked me if I solved this, and the short answer is yes, I did. Unfortunately, nobody gave me a specific answer about how to solve it,  and the problem is that I think I used a bazooka to kill a fly.

The process for solving this was this:
I updated all Firebase dependencies, I was using these:

```
      com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics,
      com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics,
      com.google.firebase:firebase-perf,
      com.google.firebase:firebase-core,
      com.google.firebase:firebase-auth,
      com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging
```

I update them using ***firebase-bom*** version ***30.3.2***

Also, I updated other google dependencies, I'm not 100% sure that this affected the solution, however, I want to document all just in case you are also using them, and you can consider it out.

```
      com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0,
      com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:18.0.1,
      com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:18.0.1,
      com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0,
      com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0,
      com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.1
```

After using these versions, I uploaded the new build and did not see the problem again in the Google console for this version and later

Sorry for not being specific in the needed dependency to be updated, I didn't have a chance to test the combinations to discover them.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the self-answer, I've noticed even with the newest `Firebase` on `Expo 47` packages the warning was still there, but only for `Open Testing`. `Production` didn't warn anything. After updating to `Expo 48`, while still keeping the newest `Firebase` packages, the warning was gone also for `Open Testing`. Maybe some deep nested dependencies, as I've done a deep clean of my project including `expo prebuild --clean`.